# Evaluate $\sum \frac{2^k}{3^{2^k}+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Evaluate the sum $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left ( \frac{2^k}{3^{2^k}+1} \right )$$

I first tried to see weather the sum actually converges, by ratio test it does as $\lim_{n\to \infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|<1$ where $a_n$ is the nth term. Now I am left with finding the actual sum. I thought to write it so that it can telescope, but can't find any suitable representations. Any hints for the evaluation part? Any Taylor polynomials etc?

Update: Wolfram says its $1/2$

Comment: Numerical evidence seems to suggest $1/2$, and this seems reasonable to me. I'll see if I can come up with a way to prove it.

Comment: @above yes I just checked wolfram, it says $1/2$. Thanks.

Comment: Look at the @RonGordon 's answer here: [A closed form for the sum $S = \frac {2}{3+1} + \frac {2^2}{3^2+1} + \cdots + \frac {2^{n+1}}{3^{2^n}+1}$ is ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119245/a-closed-form-for-the-sum-s-frac-231-frac-22321-cdots-f)

Comment: I got it doing summation by parts! But I made a sign error, so I'm going to find that error before I post.

Comment: I will be very much interested in seeing use of Abel summation, I haven't seen it in action a lot.

Comment: @Glasgow39 I deleted my post, as I think something went pretty wrong. I'm quite bad at arithmetic it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{2^k}{3^{2^k}+1}=\frac{2^k}{3^{2^k}-1}-\frac{2^{k+1}}{3^{2^{k+1}}-1}$$
So telescoping is the way to go, here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to rederive
your telescoping of
$\dfrac{2^k}{3^{2^k}+1}
=\dfrac{2^k}{3^{2^k}-1}-\dfrac{2^{k+1}}{3^{2^{k+1}}-1}
$
and see if I can generalize it.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{2^k}{3^{2^k}-1}-\dfrac{2^{k+1}}{3^{2^{k+1}}-1}
&=\dfrac{2^k(3^{2^{k+1}}-1)-2^{k+1}(3^{2^k}-1)}{(3^{2^k}-1)(3^{2^{k+1}}-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{2^k(3^{2^{k+1}}-1-2(3^{2^k}-1)}{(3^{2^k}-1)(3^{2^{k+1}}-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{2^k((3^{2^{k}})^2-2(3^{2^k}+1)}{(3^{2^k}-1)(3^{2^{k+1}}-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{2^k(3^{2^{k}}-1)^2}{(3^{2^k}-1)(3^{2^{k+1}}-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{2^k(3^{2^{k}}-1)}{(3^{2^{k+1}}-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{2^k(3^{2^{k}}-1)}{(3^{2^{k+1}})^2-1}\\
&=\dfrac{2^k(3^{2^{k}}-1)}{(3^{2^{k}}-1)(3^{2^{k}}+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{2^k}{3^{2^{k}}+1}\\
\end{array}
$

It looks like the
"3" can be anything,
while the "2" is essential
since it is used in
$x^2-1 = (x-1)(x+1)$.
So,
replacing $3$ by $m$,
this becomes

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{2^k}{m^{2^k}-1}-\dfrac{2^{k+1}}{m^{2^{k+1}}-1}
&=\dfrac{2^k(m^{2^{k+1}}-1)-2^{k+1}(m^{2^k}-1)}{(m^{2^k}-1)(m^{2^{k+1}}-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{2^k(m^{2^{k+1}}-1-2(m^{2^k}-1)}{(m^{2^k}-1)(m^{2^{k+1}}-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{2^k((m^{2^{k}})^2-2(m^{2^k}+1)}{(m^{2^k}-1)(m^{2^{k+1}}-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{2^k(m^{2^{k}}-1)^2}{(m^{2^k}-1)(m^{2^{k+1}}-1)}\\
&=\dfrac{2^k(m^{2^{k}}-1)}{m^{2^{k+1}}-1}\\
&=\dfrac{2^k(m^{2^{k}}-1)}{(m^{2^{k+1}})^2-1}\\
&=\dfrac{2^k(m^{2^{k}}-1)}{(m^{2^{k}}-1)(m^{2^{k}}+1)}\\
&=\dfrac{2^k}{m^{2^{k}}+1}\\
\end{array}
$

From this,
$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{2^k}{m^{2^{k}}+1}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{2^k}{m^{2^k}-1}-\dfrac{2^{k+1}}{m^{2^{k+1}}-1}
\right)
=\dfrac1{m-1}
$.

For $m=3$
we get OP's result.