# How to solve this summation problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Find the value of

$$\frac{1}{3+1}+\frac{2}{3^2+1}+\frac{4}{3^4+1}+\frac{8}{3^8+1}+\cdots+\frac{2^{2006}}{3^{2^{2006}}+1}$$

I try to form the summation into telescoping sum but I stuck.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1119245/42969

Comment: As @MartinR shared, I think it is duplicated...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A closed form for the sum $S = \frac {2}{3+1} + \frac {2^2}{3^2+1} + \cdots + \frac {2^{n+1}}{3^{2^n}+1}$ is ...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1119245/a-closed-form-for-the-sum-s-frac-231-frac-22321-cdots-f)

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1759891p11501464

Answer (score 8):

More generally, define $S_n = \frac{1}{3+1}+\frac{2}{3^2+1}+\frac{4}{3^4+1}+\frac{8}{3^8+1}+\cdots+\frac{2^{n}}{3^{2^{n}}+1}$.

Hint: $\frac{2^{n}}{3^{2^n}+1}=\frac{2^{n}}{3^{2^n}-1}-\frac{2^{n+1}}{3^{2^{n+1}}-1}$.

Another way is to use induction.